# Makefile to convert all *.c to *.o

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am writing a Makefile for compiling all *.c files in a directory into 
*.o . There are many *.c files so I don't want to do it on individual basis,

I tried

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

but this isn't working ... please help me understand what's going wrong here ...

Comment: what is the error msg ..

Comment: Note that the implicit rules already allow you to make `.o` files from `.c` ones. You don't need to provide your own rule for this unless you want to do something different.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a rule `OBJS`, it will do it for you

```
OBJS    = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
```

With you `.c` files in the `SRCS`, and if they are too many do:

```
SRCS    = $(wildcard *.c)
```

Then add it when you'll run `make`

```
$(NAME) : $(OBJS)
          [...]
```

Comment: Yes I always did it for all my code, it works pretty well. Let me do a pastebin to show you.

Comment: It was supposed to be a rhetorical question, but maybe you have a version of make for which this works. Which version are you using? This wouldn't work in v 3.8. The code in my answer works fine.

Comment: Had to fix something, I was wrong on the wildcard, thanks for telling me !
http://pastebin.com/F0LUd8a4

Comment: I did with an existing project already compiled, just changed the SRCS rule and it was working well. I just didn't try to compile 2 times in a row, that was what failed after, One compilation only was working fine with an already compiled project running `make re`

Answer (score 3):

Your rule maps a single `.c` file to a single `.o`, and mirrors an existing [*implicit rule*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html).

In order to generate all the `.o` files corresponding to a set of `.c` files, you can create a list of object file names from the list of `.c` files, and then make a target that depends on that list:

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)               # list of source files
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC)) # list of object files
objs : $(OBJS)                      # target
```

Then generate the object files with

```
make objs
```

This will build a `.o` file for each `.c` one.

Answer (score 3):

You told `make` how to generate a `*.o` out of a corresponding `*.c` file. (Not that you needed to, because `make` already knows as much, at least as long as you don't try anything more specific than what you wrote in your rule.)

You didn't tell make you wanted any specific `foo.o` or `bar.o`, so make does nothing.

Either add a list of object files you want generated to the Makefile, or call `make foo.o` specifically.

### ----

For what it's worth, have a look at this... there are some tricks and lessons in there, which I trust your curiosity will find out about. Most importantly, it adds compiler warnings, and automated header dependency handling.

This is assuming GNU make for e.g. `patsubst`, the existence of `find`, and GCC (for the dependency handling via `-MMD -MP`). If you want to go cross-platform, I'd suggest a meta-build system like [CMake](http://cmake.org), which I am using [myself](http://jaws.rootdirectory.de).

```
PROJNAME := MyProject
PROJDIRS := subdir1 subdir2
SRCFILES := $(shell find $(PROJDIRS) -type f -name "\*.c")
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCFILES))
DEPFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRCFILES))

WARNINGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align \
            -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations \
            -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline \
            -Wuninitialized -Wconversion -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS := -g -std=c99 $(WARNINGS)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(PROJNAME)

clean:
    -@$(RM) $(wildcard $(OBJFILES) $(DEPFILES) $(PROJNAME))

-include $(DEPFILES)

$(PROJNAME): $(OBJFILES)
    @$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^

%.o: %.c Makefile
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```